# filter.xml | cq5 | vault

Tags: filter, aem

I have a requirement wherein I have to make sure that installed package should only overwrite content of English translations (i.e. en.xml) not for other translations

[image: info]

I have got following filter

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/project">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/project/i18n/(.*)?" />
        <include pattern="/apps/project/i18n/*en(.?xml)" />
    </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

But somehow I am not able to avoid `en_gb` getting overwritten. I tried following filters:

```
/apps/uag-vrm-portal/i18n/*en(.?xml)
/apps/uag-vrm-portal/i18n/en(.xml*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is the wide filter "/apps/project". What it is trying to do is, on installing the package, it is just adding a node named "apps" and then adding a node named "apps/project" and then it is replacing everything that is under "/apps/project". So, you need to make your filter more specific. For example, the following should work in your case -

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/project/i18n">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/project/i18n(/.*)?"/>
        <include pattern="/apps/project/i18n/en(/.*)?"/>
    </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Comment: no #spock, this will not be a problem, as you can see in the filter exclude and include pattern '/apps/project/i18n' has been used

Comment: @Rupesh, I am talking about the wide filter in the root.

Comment: Changed include filter `/apps/project/i18n/en(/.*)?` and it worked for me. I have not changed my exclude filter.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding a mix of include & exclude rules inside a single filter.  You could break it up into multiple filters:

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/project/components" />
    <filter root="/apps/project/core" />
    <filter root="/apps/project/i18n/en/(.*)" />
</workspaceFilter>
```

or try to write with only exclude patterns:

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
  <filter root="/apps/project">
    <exclude pattern="/apps/project/i18n/es(.*)?" />
    <exclude pattern="/apps/project/i18n/en_gb(.*)?" />
  </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

or write multiple include patterns (an exercise I leave to you).

But the combination of `include` and `exclude` patterns are fighting each other - with no way to determine which pattern takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss something, but why can't you set the filter to the `en` node only and exclude the other english language nodes?

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/project/i18n/en">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/project/i18n/en_.*"/>
    </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

If you need all the other languages, except `en_gb` you could exclude this explicitly.